# SQL Server -- Window Function can't use " Between xx and xx"

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a window function to identify the latest row for each member that can work in 3 out of 4 servers, but there is 1 server that can't use that. May that server structure old?

I want to know if there is a solution for that, code below:

```
    CASE 
        WHEN EFF_DT = first_value(EFF_DT) over
                                (partition by Member_CK  
                                order by EFF_DT desc
                                **rows between unbounded preceding and current row**)
             OR (Member_CK  IS NULL AND Identity_CK IS NULL)
        then 'Y'
        else 'N'
    END AS [LATEST_ROW]
```

Try to emphasis inside the code but not work, the bug happens at the 3rd row:

> **rows between unbounded preceding and current row**

Error Messages:

> Incorrect syntax near 'rows'.

**UPDATE:**
Appreciated the tip, I can verify the server version is SQL SERVER 2008(SP2), other 3 servers are in 2014 or 2017 version.

Thanks to @Gordon Linoff pointed out the rows line can be delete, but then I will get another error message:

> 'first_value' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: What is `@@VERSION` on the one where you get the error? And what compatibility level is the DB set to?

Comment: please attach full query or a sample data, so we could help you on that

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for letting me know that tip, I can see 3 out of 4 are SQL Server 2017 but the one not work is SQL Server 2008(SP2)

Comment: @JiachengGao Thanks a lot, can consider this is as simple as select     CASE 
        WHEN EFF_DT = first_value(EFF_DT) over
                                (partition by Member_CK  
                                order by EFF_DT desc
                                **rows between unbounded preceding and current row**)
             OR (Member_CK  IS NULL AND Identity_CK IS NULL)
        then 'Y'
        else 'N'
    END AS [LATEST_ROW], Member_ID, Member_Name, EFF_DT from Membership

Answer (score 1):

Remove `rows`.  It is not needed:

```
first_value(EFF_DT) over (partition by Member_CK  
                          order by EFF_DT desc
                         )
```

Comment: THANKS!!!! It works, I just new to windows function and bad in logic, did try couple >= and < and not work, this save my day!

Comment: But then I get another error saying 'first_value' is not a recognized built-in function name. And I check the server version is 2008(SP2)

Comment: @nonslearn . . . Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?